# Pandas dataframe replace rows based on values in the list and resulting value is based on another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df:

```
    df = 
          category        str_column
           cat1            str1
           cat2            str2
            ...             ...
```

and a

```
   parent_df =
           category        parent_category
           cat1             parent_of_cat1
           cat2             parent_of_cat2
```

and a list

```
  faulty_categories =
     ['cat1', ...]
```

I need to get all the categories in `df` which are present in `faulty_categories` and replace them by their parent:

So, expected output:

```
       df = 

         category       str_column
         parent_of_cat1   str1
         cat2             str2
```

How to achieve this?

I tried:

```
       df.loc[df['category'].isin(faulty_categories), 'category'] = parents_df.loc[parents_df['category'].isin(faulty_categories), 'parent']
```

But, this replaced category by NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `loc` and `map`:

```
df.loc[df['category'].isin(faulty_categories), 'category'] = df['category'].map(parent_df.set_index('category')['parent_category'])
```

Or `mask` and `map`:

```
df['category'] = (df['category'].mask(df['category'].isin(faulty_categories),
                                      df['category'].map(parent_df.set_index('category')['parent_category'])
                                     )
```

Output:

```
         category str_column
0  parent_of_cat1       str1
1            cat2       str2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [2226]: import numpy as np

In [2227]: x = df.merge(parent_df)
In [2230]: x['category'] = np.where(x.category.isin(faulty_categories), x.parent_category, x.category)

In [2232]: x.drop('parent_category', 1, inplace=True)

In [2233]: x
Out[2233]: 
         category str_column
0  parent_of_cat1       str1
1            cat2       str2
```

Answer (score 1):

**df**

```
    category    str_column
0   cat1         str1
1   cat2         str2
2   cat3         str3
```

```
    category    parent_category
0   cat1        parent_of_cat1
1   cat3        parent_of_cat3
2   cat2        parent_of_cat2
```

`faulty_cat = ['cat1', 'cat3']`

**Solution:-**

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'category'] in faulty_cat:
        df.loc[i,'category'] = parent_df['parent_category'][parent_df['category'] == df.loc[i,'category']].item()
```

**Output df:-**

```
      category          str_column
0   parent_of_cat1      str1
1   cat2                str2
2   parent_of_cat3      str3
```